# how to write a query to separate each column by comma without specifying each column name

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How to write a query so that each column of table1 separated by comma
Without including each column name

```
+------+-----+-----------+-------------+
| eno  |dno  | ename     | job_type    |
+------+-----+-----------+-------------+
| 101  | 1   | sam       | manager     |
| 102  | 2   | ash       | teacher     |
| 103  | 3   | rohan     | clerk       |
| 104  | 4   | sohan     | peon        |
| 105  | 5   | mohan     | guar        |
+------+-----+------------+------------+
```

I  want to output like this

```
101,1,sam,manager      
102,2,ash,teacher
```

And rest are same

Comment: I removed the mysql tag.  Please tag only with the database that you are really using.

Comment: I think the only way to do this in SQL Server is to use dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of a CROSS APPLY (or two), a little XML and STUFF()

> **A word of caution:  This approach will EXCLUDE NULL values**

```
Declare @YourTable table (eno int,dno int, ename varchar(25),job_type varchar(25))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(101,1,'sam'  , 'manager'),
(102,2,'ash'  , 'teacher'),
(103,3,'rohan', 'clerk'  ),
(104,4,'sohan', 'peon'   ),
(105,5,'mohan', 'guar'   ) 


Select C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* for XML Raw) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select String=Stuff((Select ',' +Value 
                  From (
                        Select Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                         From  XMLData.nodes('/row') as A(r)
                         Cross Apply A.r.nodes('./@*') AS B(attr)
                       ) X
                  For XML Path ('')),1,1,'')
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
String
101,1,sam,manager
102,2,ash,teacher
103,3,rohan,clerk
104,4,sohan,peon
105,5,mohan,guar
```

Comment: That's awesome... but the first record comes out like this 1,101,manager,sam

Comment: @manderson corrected.  I removed the distinct which changed the order

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with a dynamic sql query.

**Query**

```
declare @sql as varchar(max);

select @sql = 'select case when right(t.csv, 1) = ' + char(39) + ',' + char(39) 
            + ' then left(t.csv, len(t.csv) - 1) else t.csv end as csv from(select ' 

            + stuff((select '+ case when [' + column_name + '] is null then ' 
            + char(39) + char(39) +
      ' else cast(['  + column_name + '] as varchar(max)) + ' 
            + char(39) + ',' + char(39) + ' end'
            from information_schema.columns
            where table_name = 'dds_emp'
            order by ordinal_position asc
            for xml path('')
        ), 1, 1, '');

select @sql += ' as csv from dds_emp)t;';
exec(@sql);
```